# ogr2ogr: Unable to open datasource (OCI driver)

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle-call-interface, ogr2ogr

When transferring data from the oracle database to the postgresql database, using the ogr2ogr command, an error occurs regarding the OCI driver. There is no: "OCI -vector- (rw +): Oracle Spatial" driver in the list of supported drivers (command: `ogr2ogr --formats`). The operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Command syntax: `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:dbname=dbname host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx" "OCI:user/password@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxx)(PORT = xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = xxxx))):schema.table" -overwrite -progress -a_srs EPSG:32634 -lco "SCHEMA=schemaname"`

How to add an OCI driver within the list of supported drivers.

Comment: are you running a build that has the driver bundled? similar issues might have been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783405/how-to-read-oracle-spatial-data-with-rgdal-missing-drive)